# What are the alternatives to the Calendar module?

Tags: datetime

I have a requirement to add a calendar to my Drupal 7 website. Currently the [Calendar](http://drupal.org/project/calendar) module has an alpha version. This is a little subjective, but I was wondering if the Calendar module is stable enough for my needs. Are there alternatives?

Comment: Calendar is stable enough to use. We have it deployed on several live sites already.

Comment: ok, thanks for the feedback. Personally i've just installed it. Did what it said on the tin. I'm not using in production. But it felt fairly solid

Answer (score 3):

Well, in my recent experience is not yet ready to production, but it depends on your needs. Maybe most of this is because the "partner" module, date, has lots of issues now.
I suggest you test both: Calendar and [FullCalendar](http://drupal.org/project/fullcalendar). The Calendar module is more powerful and flexible, but if you need a simple calendar, FullCalendar is ready to go now.

Comment: FullCalendar really is worth a try. I think I'll chose it over Calendar. FullCalendar looks much more native to me. They also have a [good documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1056742) available.

Answer (score 2):

The Calendar module is being rewritten from scratch, see Calendar 7.x-3.x. There will be no upgrade path.

Answer (score 1):

There also is [Bootstrap Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_calendar). But it doesn't seem to be ready for production yet. At my first simple test I didn't got it going with the default settings.

Comment: It looks like it's ready for production now, but I haven't had a chance to use it yet.